# Ejecutar script SQL al iniciar contenedor PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

estoy iniciando un contenedor con el siguiente docker-compose:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  postgresql:
    container_name: postgreSQL
    restart: always
    image: centos/postgresql-96-centos7:latest
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment:
      POSTGRESQL_USER: user
      POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRESQL_DATABASE: db
      POSTGRESQL_ADMIN_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Para iniciarlo ejecuto `docker-compose up`, pero no me crea la tabla que le indico en init.sql:

`CREATE TABLE prueba(id SERIAL Primary Key);`

init.sql está al mismo nivel que docker-compose.yml, ¿cuál puede ser el problema?

Answer (score 0):

intenta cambiar el orden en volumes:

```
- ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql    
- ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

en ocasiones si inicializas primero la carpeta data ignora los scrips.

Comment: No funciona igualmente.